# How to specify per-benchmark arguments in stack's package.yaml?

Tags: benchmarking, haskell-stack

I have a benchmark suite written with `criterion` that I invoke via `stack bench`.

My `package.yaml` contains:

```
benchmarks:
  criterion-benchmarks:
    dependencies:
      - criterion
      - linear
    ghc-options:
      - -O2
      - -threaded
      - -rtsopts
      - -with-rtsopts=-N
    main: Main.hs
    source-dirs: benchmark
```

I invoke this with:

```
stack bench --ba "--output bench.html"
```

This runs the benchmark and generates `bench.html` for viewing results.

In the [Stack YAML Configuration](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#build) documentation it shows the use of project-wide build options, implying this:

```
build:
  # ...
  benchmark-opts:
    benchmark-arguments: "--output bench.html"
```

My question is: `package.yaml` supports multiple benchmarks (children of `benchmarks:`), however I'd like to generate a different HTML output file for each one, rather than use the project-wide specification of `bench.html` and have them collide.

I haven't found any documentation that shows how to specify run-time arguments for each benchmark defined in `package.yaml`. The [hpack documentation](https://github.com/sol/hpack#quick-reference) doesn't provide any obvious options that look relevant, as Common fields, or for `test` or `bench` targets.

Is it possible?

Comment: AFAIK you can't specify different benchmark options for different benchmarks in your `stack.yaml`. It sounds like a reasonable feature though. I'd suggest opening a feature request on `stack`'s issue tracker.

Comment: @sjakobi Ok, thank you for your advice, I took it.